# RabbitMQ: direct reply-to?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

Is there a good example (C#) of how to do the direct reply-to in RabbitMQ? What I want to do is for X Producers to post a message ("I've got some work for somebody") and I want one of X Consumers to pick it up, do the work and send the response back. Not a basic Ack, but some data, the result of the calculation. Of course, the response has to go back to the right producer.

Producer:

```
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello",
                                 durable: true,
                                 exclusive: false,
                                 autoDelete: false,
                                 arguments: null);

            string message = "Hello World!";
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
            properties.Persistent = true;

            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                                 routingKey: "hello",
                                 basicProperties: properties,
                                 body: body);

            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
        }
    }
```

Consumer:

```
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello",
                                 durable: true,
                                 exclusive: false,
                                 autoDelete: false,
                                 arguments: null);

            channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
                channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
            };

            channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello",
                                 noAck: false,
                                 consumer: consumer);

            Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

It's not very clear from the minimal docs on how to set up both sides. I know somebody has to do something with the "amq.rabbitmq.reply-to" queue, but its not clear which side and what they have to do with it.

Comment: Is there a reasons you aren't using a service for this? When a message is published to a queue and an ack is received, the responsibility for the poster is effectively relinquished. A REST service would be more logical for your case.

Comment: @Tim, that is just what I have now with no response implemented. Are you talking about HTTP POSTs back and forth? As I said, I might have 5 producers, but maybe 5,000 consumers. The whole point of the message queue is to do all the coordination back and forth and "load balance" the requests.

Comment: I'm just a bit confused regarding the use case. This situation is inversed in the sense that there are usually far more consumers (application servers in your case) than "producers" . Why would you have 5000 consumers (that do work)  all waiting for a calculation request, with only 5 "work producers"? Why not just use haproxy or something similar in front of a REST service to load balance?

Comment: @Tim, not sure what the confusion is. Think of a producer as a "job submitter". A "job" is to load / process a batch (of files). A batch might contain 10,000 files. Processing a file is computationally expensive, so that work is distributed across 5,000 worker nodes. You wouldn't do it the way I describe? Consumers = worker nodes in this case, not submitters.

Comment: FYI: This isn't *really* an answer, but my [Shuttle.Esb open-source service bus](http://shuttle.github.io/shuttle-esb) that has a RabbitMQ transport with a [request-response sample](https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Esb.Samples/tree/master/Shuttle.RequestResponse).  Of course, other service bus implementations would provide the same functionality.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you seen the tutorials on the rabbitmq website? http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html

You would set up your code the same way as the RPC example, above, with only a few minor differences (noted in the docs you've referenced: https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html).

When publishing a message from the original message producer, set the "replyTo" to `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to`

Have the original message producer also be a message consumer, consuming from the `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` queue

When the code that handles the original request is done processing, you will publish a message from that worker, through the default (empty, no-name, "") exchange, with the routing key also set to `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to`

So:

- client begins consuming messages from `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` queue
- client sends request for work, with `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` as the `replyTo` property
- worker picks up message, does work, publishes a response through the "" exchange, using `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` as the routing key

that should be about it

Comment: Ok, this might get me started.. Thanks!

Comment: Even though this answer is 4yr old I'd like to point out for future reference that on the third bullet point instead of using "amq.rabbitmq.reply-to" as the routing_key, you should use whatever was received on ea.BasicProperties.ReplyTo field. If you print it you'll notice it's not the same.

Comment: Any chance you know whether this will work with multiple services consuming from `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to`? Will the reply message go to the correct consumer or one of them at random? There is no mention about this in the docs. While, I guess this should go to the right consumer (because if it didn't, I am not sure how valuable this feature would be), I am not sure how RabbitMQ figures out on which consumer it should forward the reply message.

Comment: I guess the comment from `Cyber Oliveira` above, sheds some light into how RabbitMQ deals with the message, in order to forward it to the correct consumer.